# Ruby, install dashing on windows

Tags: ruby, dashing

I try to install the Dashing framework.

My environnement is Windows 7, 64 bit. I have download ruby 1.9.3 and installed the DevKit, but I can't install Dashing.

if I write: `gem install dashing`, I receive this error:

```
C:\devkit>gem install dashing
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dashing:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)"


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.3/ext/thin_parser/gem_make.out
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your ruby path has a space in it.
Try to reinstall ruby with devkit in C:ruby

Answer (score 0):

As other variant - you can use RailsInstaller for windows. It contains devkit and it's already configured to work.